# New house ceiling lights work but not pendant lights

Tags: electrical, lighting

Been in a newly build for 15 months. Kitchen has a chandelier and 6 candle lights. All good there. We also have 3 things for pendant lights that had been covered with a plastic cap.

Today I tried to install pendant lights, but doesn't look like there's any electricity getting to those. I connected the fixture, and all lights work except for the pendant lights. I tried two of the three. I also used a small voltage checker on the wires with the power on. Nothing.

Anything obvious I'm missing before I reach out to the builder?

Comment: Look in the box where the switch is and see if there's any capped off wires.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I connected the fixture, and all lights work except for the pendant lights".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On homes where we wired the home with extra locations like your pendant lights but did not install them we did not wire the connection at the switch either.

It would not take any longer but some inspectors will flag unused hot conductors.
Or to say it differently the hot wire to that string was not connected for safety reasons.

We usually did connect the neutral and ground and would wire nut the black.
In the switch box look for a disconnected wire, that can be landed on the switched side of the switch (not always hot side) or a double switch can be added.

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out the first time I saw that done.. lol +1